# How can i get index of 1 from Arrays of Array

Tags: javascript

Im getting an Array like this [[2,4],[7,32],[76,44],[34,22]...] up to 100, i want to get 5 Arrays out of all arrays, with the index of 1 in each of the array. am getting the index of 1 in each item in the arrays but how can i get the five different item, i want to select 3 random elements(plus the first and last one). can someone please help me out.

i want to the output to be something like this

4
44
30
77
66

Here's my code

```
const items = [[2,4],[7,32],[76,44],[34,22],[10,30],[34,67],[90,13],[20,14],[78,77],[9,77],[44,66]]

items.map(item => console.log(item[1]))
```

Comment: Maybe [`.slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) as in, for example, `items.slice(1, 6)`.

Comment: Can you give a full, worked out, example (not code) of what you're trying to acheive showing the logic used at each step. It's not clear what you're actually asking for

Comment: ok, have i just editted it

Comment: Sounds like you want to select 3 random elements (plus the first and last), then get the second element in each?

Comment: How do you determine which 5 (or 3) elements to choose?

Comment: yes, exactly. want to select 3 random elements plus the first and last one

Comment: You may take a look at the source code of [loadsh.sampleSize](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/blob/master/sampleSize.js)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Update 2.0

Take 3 random items and the first and the last item from the items array and return the index 1 from each item.

```js
items = [[2,4],[7,32],[76,44],[34,22],[10,30],[34,67],[90,13],[20,14],[78,77],[9,77],[44,66]]


function action(arr) {
  const f = arr[0];
  const l = arr[arr.length-1]
  const a = arr.slice(1, arr.length-1)
  const t = [];

  for(i=0; i<3;i++) {  
    t.push(a[Math.floor(Math.random()*a.length)][1]);  
  }
  return [f[1], ...t, l[1]];
}


console.log(action(items))
```

#### old answer

`slice()` would the right approach.

```js
const items = [[2,4],[7,32],[76,44],[34,22],[10,30],[34,67],[90,13],[20,14],[78,77],[9,77],[44,66]]

function action(arr, from, to) {
  return arr.slice(from, to)
}
console.log(action(items, 1, 6));
```

Comment: Doesn't match OP's sample output.

Comment: have editted the question for more clarification

Comment: thanks, but i want to also get  of first and last items

Comment: @Emmanueluzoezie i uodated my answear again